# Criticality of a reactor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, neutrons, nuclear-engineering

How criticality of a reactor can be defined in terms of neutron interaction with matter(neutron capture, elastic scattering and fission)?

Answer (score 1):

The reactor is just critical if at any point, the production of neutrons (by fission) is equal to the disappearances (leakage + absorption). This also means that the number of neutrons present is equal to each new generation of neutrons: at this moment, the power of the reactor is constant.
During a power increase, the reactor will be slightly overcritical.
During a power decrease, the reactor will be slightly subcritical.